# How to generate 2 columns of incremental values and all their unique combinations with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, combinations, intervals

I need to create a 2 columns dataframe.

The first column contains values from 7000 until 15000 and all the increments of 500 in that range (7000,7500,8000...14500,1500)

The second column contain all the integers from 6 to 24

I need a simple way to generate these values and all their unique combinations:

```
6,7000
6,7500
6,8000
....
24,14500
24,15000
```

Comment: `The second column contain all the integers from 6 to 24`...It can be random? I mean can it be `6 24 6 6 24 ...`

Comment: it contains all the integers from 6 to 24. 6,7,8,9,10,,,24

Comment: Use `range` with `step`: `pd.DataFrame([(x,y) for x in range(6,25) for y in range(7000,15001,500)])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) for generating sequence of numbers, [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) for generating *cross-product* and stack them using [`numpy.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html#:%7E:text=c_-,numpy.,because%20of%20its%20common%20occurrence.) or [`numpy.column_stack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)

```
x = np.arange(6, 25)
y = np.arange(7000, 15001, 500)

pd.DataFrame(np.c_[x.repeat(len(y)),np.tile(y, len(x))])
# pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x.repeat(len(y)),np.tile(y, len(x))]))
      0      1
0     6   7000
1     6   7500
2     6   8000
3     6   8500
4     6   9000
..   ..    ...
318  24  13000
319  24  13500
320  24  14000
321  24  14500
322  24  15000

[323 rows x 2 columns]
```

Another idea is to use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
from itertools import product
pd.DataFrame(list(product(x,y)))
```

Timeit results:

```
# Henry' answer in comments
In [44]: %timeit pd.DataFrame([(x,y) for x in range(6,25) for y in range(7000,15001,500)])
657 µs ± 169 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

# My solution
In [45]: %%timeit
    ...: x = np.arange(6, 25)
    ...: y = np.arange(7000, 15001, 500)
    ...: 
    ...: pd.DataFrame(np.c_[x.repeat(len(y)),np.tile(y, len(x))])
    ...:
    ...:
155 µs ± 13.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

#Using `np.column_stack`
In [49]: %%timeit
    ...: x = np.arange(6, 25)
    ...: y = np.arange(7000, 15001, 500)
    ...: 
    ...: pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([x.repeat(len(y)),np.tile(y, len(x))]))
    ...:
121 µs ± 10.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# `itertools.product` solution
In [62]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(list(product(x,y)))
489 µs ± 7.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```